# Call variables from .py script into Batch

Tags: python, batch-file, pycharm

I have a series of .py files that I am using a .bat for to automate the whole process. Within some of the .py files I have called variables from another .py file. I did this to allow myself to only change one .py when running new processes. I have the .bat set up to run normally with the .py files, but I do not understand how to incorporate the variables.py file.

Example:

Python1.py

```
import os
import somefolder.variables as variables

path = 'C:/pictures/'
file = variables.file

for img in os.listdir(path + variables.file):
    print(img)
```

Variables.py

```
file = item1.img
```

Batch.bat

```
call "C:/Users/name/anaconda3/Scripts/activate.bat" "C:/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/environment"
call "C:/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/environment/python.exe" "D:/Scripts/python1.py"
...
```

After running something similar to this. I received the error: `No module named 'somefolder'`. I've read a few other posts about using the `echo` command or using `set`, but it seems as that is setting a variable within the batch and not calling it from another .py file. I am farily new to batch files, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't actually an issue with how you are using your bat file. This is a pathing issue in python. You are using relative import statements but you are not in the folder of your python files when you do it, so it can't find the file to import.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Why does it work when I just run the .py script by itself?

Comment: When you run the script by itself you are most likely running it from the same directory. So then the relative path is correct at that point.

Comment: So do I need to add the python1.py file to my environment?

Comment: Not sure, that might work but I wouldn't do that. First it's a messy solution and not really sustainable on larger projects. Second, it's also getting into system variables that don't need to be touched. You need to look into `__init__.py` and package files. That's the pythonic way of solving this issue.

Comment: Yeah I think that would be best as well. For now I ended up using `sys.path.append('C:/..module/)` and then just `import variables`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rashid 'Lee' Ibrahim mentioned in the comments above, it would be best to look into using  `__intit__.py`. Though for the sake of getting the code to run, I set where the module/.py file was located as a system path.

Python1.py Original

```
import os
import somefolder.variables as variables

path = 'C:/pictures/'
file = variables.file

for img in os.listdir(path + variables.file):
    print(img)
```

Python1.py Edited

```
import os
sys.path.append('D:/Scripts/')
import variables

path = 'C:/pictures/'
file = variables.file

for img in os.listdir(path + variables.file):
    print(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read file contents into a variable:

`for /f "delims=" %%x in (version.txt) do set Build=%%x`

or

`set /p Build=<version.txt`

Both will act the same with only a single line in the file, for more lines the for variant will put the last line into the variable, while set /p will use the first.

Using the variable – just like any other environment variable – it is one, after all:

`%Build%`

So to check for existence:

`if exist \\fileserver\myapp\releasedocs\%Build%.doc ...`

Although it may well be that no UNC paths are allowed there. Can't test this right now but keep this in mind.

Comment: Is this reading variables from a .txt? What if I am pulling from a .py? Can I just change the file type?